# PHP mySql isnt inserting into Database

Tags: php, mysql

```
$insert = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO user set fname=:fname, lname=:lname, uname=:uname, email=:email, password=:hashPass'); 
            $insert->bindParam(':fname', $fname);
            $insert->bindParam(':lname', $lname);
            $insert->bindParam(':uname', $uname);
            $insert->bindParam(':email', $email);
            $insert->bindParam(':hashPass', $hashPass);
            $insert->execute();
```

It is not inserting anything into my database. All variables have values and other mySQL statements are working however I cant seem to insert data into the table? Using `PDO::Errorcode()` returns `00000`

Comment: You're not checking for errors. How do you expect to know what's wrong if you don't bother to look?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see your query is mixed up INSERT and UPDATE statements syntax.

Instead of:

> prepare('INSERT INTO user set fname=:fname, lname=:lname, uname=:uname, email=:email, password=:hashPass');

try this one:

> prepare('INSERT INTO user (fname, lname, uname, email, password) VALUES (:fname, :lname, :uname, :email, :hashPass');